# Tikzpicture: random sample of points on the real line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to illustrate how the concept of centrality of data points is hard to generalize in higher dimensions when facing multivariate analysis.

To this end, I begin by explaining and illustrating how natural ordering data points is when working with univariate data. So, I'm trying to draw the following picture in LaTeX using tikz :

[image]

What I've done so far is use an R script to generate a *.dat* file containing the coordinates of random points sampled from a normal distribution and then tried to plot them in the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[only marks]
        \draw plot[mark=*] file {random_numbers.dat};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When compiling my document, I get the following error: *Missing number, treated as zero.*

Any response to one of the following questions would be very much appreciated !

1. How do I fix the error ?
2. How can I color the data points and draw the lines according to the picture I'm trying to reproduce ?
3. Is there a way to not use a *.dat* file for this task ? Reading through the documentation of the tikz & pgf packages, it seems that mathematical expressions can be evaluated and plotted but I'm not sure that there are tools to sample observations from a particular distribution.

**EDIT:**

The *.dat* file stores the random numbers like this:

| "x" | "y" |
| --- | --- |
| 1.52516422413456 | 0 |
| -1.84552933493078 | 0 |
| 0.599154946213978 | 0 |
| ... | ... |

where the two columns are separated by spaces.

**REMARK:**

Using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669948/287411), I've raised another error when I added the following command to my preamble:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

I fixed it by adding this after loading the french babel package:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{?}
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please edit your post and copy your .dat files content? Format isn‘t clear to me. // Is there a change when you remove the space for file{ ?

Comment: @MS-SPO thanks for you reply. I've tried compiling the same code where the space you mentionned was removed but it didn"t work. I've provided the structure of my .dat file.

Comment: Thanks for adding. // Recalling chapter 22.4 in the pgfmanual, can it be that you miss the first line like "#Curve 0, 20 points"? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf // The example there also ends each line with "i" for the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents}{tmp_random_numbers.dat}
-1.53   0
-0.95   0
1.04    0
1.58    0
-0.97   0
-0.86   0
0.58    0
0.85    0
0.49    0
-1.37   0
-0.73   0
1.84    0
-0.03   0
-1.04   0
-1.79   0
-0.48   0
-1.37   0
1.17    0
-0.12   0
-1.56   0
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
axis lines=center,
axis y line=none,
ticks=none, 
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=0, ymax=0,
filter discard warning=false,
]
\addplot[red,   only marks, x filter/.expression={x<-1.5||x>1.5?x:nan}] table {tmp_random_numbers.dat};
\addplot[blue,  only marks, x filter/.expression={x>-1.5&&x<1.5?x:nan}] table {tmp_random_numbers.dat};
\addplot[green, only marks] coordinates {(0,0)};
\node[pin={[pin distance=0.5cm, pin edge={black}]{centre}}] at (0,0) {};
\node (outliers) at (0,-1.5cm) {outliers};
\draw (-1.9,-2pt) -- (outliers) (1.9,-2pt) -- (outliers);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: x axis with different colored dots]